# Turn one string of multiple numbers separated by commas into array of integers in ruby

Tags: ruby

How to turn `"1,2,3,4,500,645"` into `[1,2,3,4,500,645]` in Ruby.
.to_i only returns the first number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if commas just divide integers

```
"1,2,3,4,500,645".split(',').map(&:to_i)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 500, 645]
```

if you are not sure what's in the string and you want everything breaks if something not expected is there

```
"1,2,3,4,500,645".split(',').map { |i| Integer(i) }
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 500, 645]
```

Comment: You may want `.map { |i| Integer(i) }` if you want an error on bad input